# MultiSubnetFailover option not supported on one server?

Tags: clustering, mirroring

I have a SQL Server Cluster with Availability Groups. I connect to that server from a Windows 2012 R2 server with PHP 7.0.18 and Apache using ODBC and PHP ODBC Drivers.

I have two Windows 2012 R2 servers with the same installation's and configurations. When i try to connect to the SQL Server using the Listener and the parameters multiSubnetFailover=yes;ConnectionPooling=0;  it will fail on the 2nd 2012 Server. But from the 1st server the connection will be successful.

The error message I get on the 2nd server is:

> Connecting to a mirrored SQL server instance using the MultiSubnetFailover connection option is not supported.

When i set MultiSubnetFailover to no it will connect successfully, but I want to set it on yes.

Is there anyone who also had this problem and was able to solve it?

Comment: Have you set up OR condition in IP dependency in MultiSubnet Failover cluster GUI. Please check [this msdn thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bd71c790-126e-4c73-85cb-e3fe22cf8ba5/sql-server-agent-fails-to-connect-to-db-after-enabling-mirror-on-failover-cluster?forum=sqldatabasemirroring) and see answer given by MSFT team

Comment: I have the exact same issue. What SQL Version and CU do you have? Got SQL2016 SP1 CU3 here. Have you set up the databases using "direct seed" ?

Comment: Got it here. It seems to be important that the connection string points to the AG listener and not directly to the server when using this option. I was pointing it direct for some tests